# Pervasive PSQL having trouble with inner join

Tags: sql, pervasive

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXW0f.png)

```
CREATE VIEW "V_BACKLOG" 
    AS SELECT JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB, JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX, JOB_OPERATIONS.SEQ, JOB_OPERATIONS.PART, JOB_OPERATIONS.DESCRIPTION, JOB_OPERATIONS.ROUTER_SEQ, JOB_OPERATIONS.FLAG_CLOSED, JOB_OPERATIONS.WORK_STARTED, JOB_HEADER.SALES_ORDER, JOB.HEADER.SALES_ORDER_LINE, JOB.HEADER.DATE_OPENED, JOB_HEADER.CUSTOMER_PO, JOB_HEADER.DATE_DUE, JOB_HEADER.QTY_ORDER, JOB_HEADER.CUSTOMER, JOB_HEADER.DESCRIPTION 
    FROM JOB_OPERATIONS  
    INNER JOIN JOB_HEADER WHERE JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB = JOB_HEADER.JOB AND JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX = JOB_HEADER.SUFFIX
    ORDER BY JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB, JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX, JOB_OPERATIONS.SEQ
```

Creating a join here and I've been looking it over trying to figure out why the engine won't parse it. I'm doing a slow elimination by testing other queries that have all but 1 similar qualities but if anyone can illuminate me I would appreciate it.

EDIT

```
CREATE VIEW "testing" 
AS SELECT JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB,
    JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX,
    JOB_OPERATIONS.PART,
    JOB_HEADER.QTY_ORDER,
    JOB_HEADER.CUSTOMER

FROM JOB_OPERATIONS

LEFT JOIN JOB_HEADER ON 
    (JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB = JOB_HEADER.JOB AND
    JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX = JOB_HEADER.SUFFIX)

ORDER BY JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB, JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX
```

this works

```
CREATE VIEW "V_BACKLOG" 
AS SELECT JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB, 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX, 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.SEQ, 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.PART, 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.DESCRIPTION, 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.ROUTER_SEQ, 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.FLAG_CLOSED, 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.WORK_STARTED, 
    JOB_HEADER.SALES_ORDER, 
    JOB.HEADER.SALES_ORDER_LINE, 
    JOB.HEADER.DATE_OPENED, 
    JOB_HEADER.CUSTOMER_PO, 
    JOB_HEADER.DATE_DUE, 
    JOB_HEADER.QTY_ORDER, 
    JOB_HEADER.CUSTOMER, 
    JOB_HEADER.DESCRIPTION 

FROM JOB_OPERATIONS

LEFT JOIN JOB_HEADER ON 
    (JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB = JOB_HEADER.JOB AND 
    JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX = JOB_HEADER.SUFFIX)

ORDER BY JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB, JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX, JOB_OPERATIONS.SEQ
```

but this does not, which i find confusing

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` requires an `ON` condition. Just change your `WHERE` with `ON`.

Comment: Why didn't you post the error message, didn't you think that might help finding the error?

Comment: The error message truncates all meaningful parts because the select condition is displayed in entirety.

Answer (score 0):

You need different clause "where -> on"

```
CREATE VIEW "V_BACKLOG" 
AS SELECT JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB, JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX, JOB_OPERATIONS.SEQ, JOB_OPERATIONS.PART, JOB_OPERATIONS.DESCRIPTION, JOB_OPERATIONS.ROUTER_SEQ, JOB_OPERATIONS.FLAG_CLOSED, JOB_OPERATIONS.WORK_STARTED, JOB_HEADER.SALES_ORDER, JOB.HEADER.SALES_ORDER_LINE, JOB.HEADER.DATE_OPENED, JOB_HEADER.CUSTOMER_PO, JOB_HEADER.DATE_DUE, JOB_HEADER.QTY_ORDER, JOB_HEADER.CUSTOMER, JOB_HEADER.DESCRIPTION 
FROM JOB_OPERATIONS  
INNER JOIN JOB_HEADER on JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB = JOB_HEADER.JOB AND JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX = JOB_HEADER.SUFFIX
ORDER BY JOB_OPERATIONS.JOB, JOB_OPERATIONS.SUFFIX, JOB_OPERATIONS.SEQ
```

Comment: This did not work, but that was an error I had overlooked when re-writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Pervasive was having a problem with the fact that I had two columns named "Description" in the same view.

Comment: Of course it does, a view is a little like a table, you simply can't have two columns with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems perfectly in order and you say the length of the select is obscuring the error in the error message. So this is what I would try. Starting with your test query that works, add in one element at a time until you hit the error. That way you will know where the error is and if necessary can delete elements until you have a short enough query to see the actual error.

Also as a first test, see if the view with that name already exists. If it does, then you can't create the view without dropping it first.